# Google Chrome Developer Tools sometimes not opening css files?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I have a class that I've inspected:

[image]

Occasionally the right text refers to an incorrect source of the class definition. Instead of saying `screen-site.css:783`, it shows the last part of the url (`web-upload`), along with `..:13`

When I click on that link, it brings me to an source file, instead of the css file:

[image]

The `13` value does not change, even if I add/remove lines in the source and css.

It looks like a bug in Chrome, but I thought I would ask here to see if I'm doing something wrong.

**Update**

As requested, here is the HTML excerpt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type'>
    <link href="/assets/screen-site.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
```

Keep in mind that this is happening to *every* class defined in the css, not just the one I mentioned. The css is quite large, but many lines down, the class definition:

```
#main {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Can we see the page that this problem occurs on?

Comment: @Mooseman I can give you an extract, but can't give you the full thing due to NDA reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I found the culprit. The experiments option for `Support for SASS` breaks it.

[image]

Turning the option off and reopening the tools makes the names and links appear correctly. I turned it on earlier to see what it would do without remembering to turn it off. :)